# Eclipse m2e plugin stopped changing classpath to add dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have used the m2e plugin in luna 4.4.1 for a while for handling dependencies and it worked fine. Normally, I create new Java projects then convert them into a Maven project.

I decided I wanted to start using the standard Maven directory layout, so for my most recent project I created it as a Maven project and then added the Eclipse Java facet so that Eclipse would treat it like a Java project.

This has broken Maven, so that it is no longer making it's dependencies available to new projects. Normally, Eclipse adds a "Maven Managed Dependencies" library to a project with Maven dependencies; new projects no longer do this and the dependencies are never added to the project classpath. Projects that had been working before still add and remove them normally.

I have narrowed the problem down to a .classpath error; for some reason m2e has stopped modifying the project classpath to make it's dependencies available. I can work around it by manually copying and pasting the entries from a working project but I would like to find a way to "re-automate" it correctly.

Comment: Does the maven build complete? If so the dependencies may be placed in the target directories webapp/WEB-INF/lib directory despite them not showing up in the project structure.

Comment: @Continuity8 It does finish and there is no webapp directory.

Comment: First does your build work on command line? Afterwards import this into Eclipse using m2e plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: Maven and eclipse are not particularly happy partners and require some management, you need to update your eclipse project every time you add dependencies to the pom file.   Right click on the project and click `maven> update project `

Comment: @redge I've tried that to no avail.

Comment: Do you really need to have java facet on a maven project ? I think m2e is very clever plugin and takes care of all class path issues very well. If you have created a  maven project from command line , then you need to import it as "Maven project# and not as a normal "java project."

Comment: @Shinchan The problem isn't that adding the java facet to one project messed up that project, it's that in every single new project I made afterwards, I can't use any of Maven's dependencies, regardless of how I create the project.

Comment: OK. Trial and error solution ... Reinstall m2e

Answer (score 0):

I have sidestepped the issue by finally buckling down to learn Gradle.